# custom Google Analytics Query Explorer 2 form

Tags: analytics, explorer

I want to make a form just like "Google Analytics Query Explorer 2" with some extra fields. Query generated with this form will be saved in DB and used to fetch Google Analytics periodically.

How can I create it in such a way that I can fetch all Accounts, Properties, Views and Ids directly from google on each onChange in these fields??

Answer (score 0):

Very slow responding community. Ok, no need to answer I have done it somehow.